# laravel routing and 404 error

Tags: routes, laravel, laravel-4

I want to specify that if anything entered in the url address other than existing routes (in routes.php, then show 404 page.

I know about this:

```
App::abort(404);
```

but how can I specify the part where everything else except the routes defined?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can add this to your filters.php file:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

And create the `errors.missing` view file to show them the error.

Also take a look at the [Errors & Logging docs](http://laravel.com/docs/errors)

**EDIT**

If you need to pass data to that view, the second parameter is an array you can use:

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array('url' => Request::url()), 404);
});
```

Comment: How can I pass Request:url() to missign blade.

Comment: Edited to answer your question.

Comment: Hello... it's possible to get the previous url to add a link in the 404 page like "Go to previous page"?

Comment: I am using `Laravel 5.2` and `filters.php` is not available. Can you suggest what I should do ?

Comment: @Helper in Laravel 5, you could open your `app/Http/Exceptions/Handler.php` file, then in the `render()` method, add this check: `if ($e->getStatusCode() == 404) { return response()->view('errors.customView', ['data' => 'custom_data'], $e->getStatusCode()); }`

Comment: You can just add `404.blade.php` in `resources/views/errors`, Laravel will handle the rest.

Answer (score 5):

I would advice putting this into your `app/start/global.php` as that is where Laravel handles it by default (though `filters.php` will also work). I usually use something like this:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Error Handler
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may handle any errors that occur in your application, including
| logging them or displaying custom views for specific errors. You may
| even register several error handlers to handle different types of
| exceptions. If nothing is returned, the default error view is
| shown, which includes a detailed stack trace during debug.
|
*/

App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    $pathInfo = Request::getPathInfo();
    $message = $exception->getMessage() ?: 'Exception';
    Log::error("$code - $message @ $pathInfo\r\n$exception");

    if (Config::get('app.debug')) {
        return;
    }

    switch ($code)
    {
        case 403:
            return Response::view('errors/403', array(), 403);

        case 500:
            return Response::view('errors/500', array(), 500);

        default:
            return Response::view('errors/404', array(), $code);
    }
});
```

Then just make an `errors` folder inside `/views` and place your error page content there. As Antonio mentioned you can pass data inside the `array()`.

I kindly borrowed this method from https://github.com/andrewelkins/Laravel-4-Bootstrap-Starter-Site

Comment: am using `Laravel 5.2` and `app/start/global.php` is not available. Can you suggest what I should do ?

Answer (score 2):

Just for guys using Laravel 5, there is an errors folder in in the views directory. You just need to create a 404.blade.php file there and it will render this view when there is no route specified for a url

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach just for displaying the error 404 with a template layout. Just add the following code to `/app/start/global.php` file

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    $layout = \View::make('layouts.error');
    $layout->content = \View::make('views.errors.404');
    return Response::make($layout, 404);
});
```