# 404 Error Handling in Laravel 5.2.15

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I am asking this question because I did not get reply after adding my comment in this question

[laravel routing and 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474556/laravel-routing-and-404-error/25629983#comment58907028_25629983)

In the above answer, we can see below code to be used in `filters.php`

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

But, I think we don't have `filters.php` in latest version. Can somebody suggest better way to handle 404 error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need to do that anymore.  Don't include that.  What you do is put a view file (your 404 error view) called `404.blade.php` in your `resources/views/errors` folder and Laravel will handle 404 errors for you.

Answer (score 0):

take a look 
http://www.jeffmould.com/2016/05/25/laravel-5-error-handling/

I just change this line App/Exceptions/Handler.php file.

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
    {
        // the below code is for Whoops support. Since Whoops can open some security holes we want to only have it
        // enabled in the debug environment. We also don't want Whoops to handle 404 and Validation related exceptions.
        if (config('app.debug') && !($e instanceof ValidationException) && !($e instanceof HttpResponseException))
        {

 /******************here I changed**********************/


           # return $this->renderExceptionWithWhoops($e);
           return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
        }


        // this line allows you to redirect to a route or even back to the current page if there is a CSRF Token Mismatch
        if($e instanceof TokenMismatchException){
            return redirect()->route('index');
        }       

        // let's add some support if a Model is not found 
        // for example, if you were to run a query for User #10000 and that user didn't exist we can return a 404 error
        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            return response()->view('errors.404', [], 404);
        }  

        // Let's return a default error page instead of the ugly Laravel error page when we have fatal exceptions
        if($e instanceof \Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException) {
            return \Response::view('errors.500',array(),500);
        }

        // finally we are back to the original default error handling provided by Laravel
        if($this->isHttpException($e))
        {
            switch ($e->getStatusCode()) {
                // not found
                case 404:
                    return \Response::view('errors.404',array(),404);
                break;
                // internal error
                case 500:
                    return \Response::view('errors.500',array(),500);   
                break;

                default:
                    return $this->renderHttpException($e);
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return parent::render($request, $e);
        }      
 /******************here I changed**********************/

        #return parent::render($request, $e);
    }

     if (config('app.debug') && !($e instanceof ValidationException) && !($e instanceof HttpResponseException))
            {
```