# Why error handling is not working in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have set the debug to true on `.env` file. Added the exceptions correctly but when i am passing invalid or not exist in my database its showing me 404 error but here I put the custom error handling value. Here is my code. (also I put "Use Expectation;" on top so no need of \Expectation)

```
public function show($id)
    {
        //only one author with id
        try
        {
            $event = Event::with('eventCategory')->findOrFail($id);
            return new EventsResource($event);
            //return one author
        }
        catch(Expectation $e)
        {   
            report($e);
            return response()->json(['status'=> false, 'message'=>'invalid data'],200);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [laravel routing and 404 error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20474556/laravel-routing-and-404-error)

Comment: In catch block its Exception not Expectation

Comment: You can use


} catch (\Exception $ex) {

I will suggest better to use if you are on PHP7


} (\Throwable $ex) {

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @user3532758 is implying, you probably want to be catching the base `Exception` not `Expectation`.

Also make sure you are referencing `Exception` from the root namespace, assuming the code you have shown is in a Controller:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    ...
}
```

[PHP Manual - Classes - Exception](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php)

Comment: I am really sorry!! Its a silly mistake. I am new to laravel but thats not the mater i should have to check properly.

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean Exception? Because in your question it's Expectation...